# NGINX-RTMP-MODULE: [error] hls: force fragment split

Tags: nginx, http-live-streaming, rtmp

I am trying to transcode incoming live RTMP stream to HLS stream using nginx-rtmp-module.

The HLS streaming works fine for few seconds and then it starts throwing the following error:

> 2020/08/22 00:14:18 [error] 10#10: *3 hls: force fragment split: 10.027 sec, , client: 127.0.0.1, server: 0.0.0.0:1935

This is my nginx configuration file.

```
daemon off;

error_log /dev/stdout info;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

rtmp {
    server {
        listen ${RTMP_PORT};
        chunk_size 4000;

        application stream {
            live on;

            exec ffmpeg -i rtmp://localhost:1935/stream/$name -v verbose
              -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k -c:v libx264 -b:v 2500k -f flv -g 150 -r 30 -s 1280x720 -preset superfast -profile:v baseline rtmp://localhost:1935/hls/$name_720p2628kbs;
        }

        application hls {
            live on;
            hls on;
            hls_fragment_naming sequential;
            hls_fragment 5s;
            hls_max_fragment 10s;
            hls_playlist_length 20s;
            hls_path /opt/data/hls;
            hls_nested on;

            hls_variant _720p2628kbs BANDWIDTH=2628000,RESOLUTION=1280x720;
        }
    }
}

http {
    access_log /dev/stdout combined;

    ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;

    server {
        listen ${HTTP_PORT};

        location /hls {
            types {
                application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;
                video/mp2t ts;
            }
            root /opt/data;
            add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        }

        location /live {
          alias /opt/data/hls;
          types {
              application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;
              video/mp2t ts;
          }
          add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
          add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        }

        location /stat {
            rtmp_stat all;
            rtmp_stat_stylesheet static/stat.xsl;
        }

        location /static {
            alias /www/static;
        }

        location = /crossdomain.xml {
            root /www/static;
            default_type text/xml;
            expires 24h;
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me with this issue?